# A question about the condition for one-to-one linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image: theorem of one-to-one transformation]

I don't understand why the condition for one-to-one T must be using a homogeneous system. I'm thinking, one-to-one corresponds to unique solution in the system. But even T(x)=b can have unique solution as well! I tried to read the proof of the theorem but it just takes homogeneous system as granted, without explaining why the theorem stands using homogeneous system!

I want to understand intuitively how this theorem works. And why homogeneous system must be used. I also want to know what have I missed in my foundation that I have this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The theorem would go through fine if it used a consistent non-homogeneous equation instead (having exactly one solution to $Tx=0$ is equivalent to having exactly one solution to $Tx=b$ whenever the latter equation is consistent). The trick is that except for $b=0$ we don’t know for which $b$ the equation will be consistent, so it’s easier to phrase the theorem this way. Also, the set of solutions to $Tx=0$ forms a subspace (the kernel of $T$), which is very important in understanding the behavior of $T$, so it is nice to phrase theorems in terms of this subspace.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem you quote does not take the uniqueness of the solution to the homogeneous system "for granted". It takes the uniqueness of a solution to the homogeneous system as a *hypothesis* and proves that as a consequence, the transformation is one-to-one (everywhere).

Since the theorem says "if and only if" it also proves the converse: if the transformation is one-to-one then the homogeneous system has a unique solution. That direction requires no extra work.

Answer (score 1):

This theorem says $T$ is one one if and only if $Ker(T)$ is trivial.

$$Ker(T)=\{x\in V:T(x)=0\}$$

If $Ker(T)$ is non trivial, then there exists a non zero vector $y$ such that $T(y)=0$. But we also know that $T(0)=0$, so $T$ is not one one anymore.

I leave the converse part for you.

Thanks!